# Python function annotation for method

Tags: python, annotations

I have been using function annotations up until now.  For example: `def print_str(text: str)`

I am passing a method into another method as an argument.  For example: `def my_function(input_function)`

Is there a function annotation for a method?  When I say `type(input_function)`, it returns `function`.  So should I say: `def my_function(input_function: function)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
from typing import Callable

def feeder(get_next_item: Callable[[], str]) -> None:
    # Body
```

And also have a look at the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html